# filling missing value code error in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying two ways of filling out missing value, one works the other doesn't. (i'm on google colab), with following version of pyspark

```
!pip install pyspark==3.0.1 py4j==0.10.9
```

**Code works:**

```
data.na.fill(value=0, subset=["data", "open"]).na.fill(value='unknown', subset=["high"]).show(5)
```

**Code that not work**

```
data.na.fill({'high':0}).show(5)
```

Returns me error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in raise_from(e)

AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "market.cap" among (_c0, symbol, data, open, high, low, close, volume, adjusted, market.cap, sector, industry, exchange); did you mean to quote the `market.cap` column?;
```

A friendly guest left a comment just now (but then quickly deleted for some reason) that the error is due to the col name `market.cap`. Thank him for pointing it out. I should be more clearer about my major concern here. Why the `market.cap` col causing issue with the 2nd line of the command but not the first line of command. And how may I fix this col name?

Comment: I was the one who made that comment, but removed it because I realized it was not relevant to the code you used. I'm equally confused why it caused problems with the second code, but not the first one.

Comment: Feels like some sort of bug to me. If the second code caused problems, why can't you just use the syntax in the first code?

Comment: @mck thank you. :). Just felt the 2nd way is neater if I have multiple cols requiring different type of modification, and many times I pick whichever one I found handy and prob not even aware of other ways of coding.  But absolutely, I can use the 1st approach as we know it works now. :-)

Comment: It's a known [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34417) in Spark 3.0.1, but resolved in Spark 3.1.2.

Comment: @mck for learning purpose, may i ask how you found the page for this bug so easily.  :D
Where and What did you search?

Comment: You can search for bugs on Jira (the linked page in my previous comment) - that's where all Spark bug reports are. Just search for something like `fillna` or `na.fill`

Answer (score 0):

I did not reach the root of the bug but...

...use `` "`market.cap`" `` as a workaround

I actually had the same "." in the title of one of my columns so that triggered the error whilst for the other columns the error was not returned.